# php rename() works with argv but not using php://stdin

Tags: php, stdin, argv

I realize some other things need to be re factored here but just trying to get the prompt to work for now.

I want to rename a folder. This works when using argv but not when prompting for the new name.

calling with php rename.php foo works

rename.php

```
$baseDir = __DIR__.'\\app\\';
$name = $argv[1];
if(is_dir($baseDir.'src')) {
    rename($baseDir.'src',  $baseDir.$name);
}
```

prompting for new name throws error

```
PHP Warning: rename(C:\Users\lotus\projects\apisUWontHate\app\src,C:\Users\lotus\projects\apisUWontHate\app\foo
): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123)
```

rename.php

```
$baseDir = __DIR__.'\\app\\';

echo 'Enter the name for your app. This will be the root namespace.';
$handle = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$name = fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);

if(is_dir($baseDir.'src')) {
    rename($baseDir.'src',  $baseDir.$name);
}
```

I tried checking the type and echoing out the result but both are exactly the same

```
echo gettype($name);// string
echo $baseDir.$name;// C:\Users\lotus\projects\apisUWontHate\app\foo
```

Am I not using stdin correctly here or is there something else that could cause the error message?

Comment: Unless your filename ends in a linefeed character, you need to trim the input from fgets() as it includes the new line

Comment: When reading from stdin (and with fgets), you usually get an additional linebreak; which is what the warning likely complains about.

Comment: @MarkBaker you wanna put that as an answer? I'll accept it since you were first. Fastest answer on SO ever :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your filename ends in a linefeed character, you need to trim the input from fgets() as it includes the new line

Quoting from the php.net doc page for [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline
>   (**which is included in the return value**), or an EOF (whichever
>   comes first).

(my emphasis)